# Difference between SSDs and 3.5 inch

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I wanted to understand the difference between hard drives and 3.5-inch SSDs. I also heard of SATA hard drives. Do you have any explanation for these differences? In particular, I read two articles on the same site and in the same year that give the consumption of both kinds of really different disks. So I do not understand too. Is that both can replace the hard drive CPU or SSD is just an addition to what already exists?
Here is the link of the two articles cited
http://www.tomshardware.fr/articles/via-c7,2-491-5.html
http: ... //www.tomshardware.fr/articles/SSD-disque-dur-cons

Comment: The 2nd link you posted doesn't work... and your question is off topic here sadly as it's too broad. But simply, it's how the data is stored on the disk and how it is written and read to and from disc... It is trasmitted via cable (SATA or IDE). Look up `advantages of ssd` and you'll find out what you need, then look up `advantages of sata` in your favourite search engine.. It should get you going :)

Comment: Thank you, I want now to know the consumption of these two types of hard disks. Do you have any idea of it?

Comment: What do you mean by consumption? Power consumption?

Comment: Yes power consumption!

Comment: Your question doesn't state that - and if that is your actual question then this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748642/how-do-i-force-exchange-to-redownload-emails-that-have-been-archived

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hard Disk Drive (HDD)**

These contain a stack of rotating disks (platters) that spin at high speeds. Little arms with lasers on the end jump across these platters in order to read or write data (physically burn grooves) from and to the disk.

**Solid State Drives (SSD)**

SSDs are relatively new to the market and don't operate in the same way. Solid State means that there are no moving parts and so the platters are gone. They instead use something called 'flash memory'. These are much faster as the PC doesn't need to wait for the disk to rotate to the part it needs to read data from.

**SATA**

This is literally just a type of connection, the most common kind these days, for hooking drives up to a motherboard and is common among both HDDs and SSDs.

A good article on the differences between HDDs and SSDs that goes into a bit more depth can be found [here](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/210492-extremetech-explains-how-do-ssds-work).

**Power consumption**

SSDs generally draw less power than HDDs, again no moving parts. The effect this has on the overall power consumption, however, is minimal. One user [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/ssd-vs-hdd-power-usage.645232/) reports that they noticed 20 to 30 mins extra battery life in their laptop but that's pretty much the maximum you would expect to see swapping between them on a consumer grade system.

Comment: Thank you for your help, do you have any idea of the power consumption of this two types of materials?

Comment: As with anything I would imagine that would vary between models. In modern systems, the power consumption of drives doesn't matter all too much though unless you're building a datacentre. Perhaps if you could explain why you're wanting to know we could be of more help?

Comment: I just make research to save power consumption in creating softwares which don't use lots of power. So I would know the impact of the consumption in active mode on the hard disk.

Comment: Edited the answer